# diferences between behat documentation and real live. What it's wrong?

Tags: behat

When I run `$ vendor/bin/behat --init`

I get this:

```
<?php

use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\PyStringNode;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\TableNode;

/**
 * Defines application features from the specific context.
 */
class FeatureContext implements Context
{
    /**
     * Initializes context.
     *
     * Every scenario gets its own context instance.
     * You can also pass arbitrary arguments to the
     * context constructor through behat.yml.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }
}
```

But the [documentation](http://behat.org/en/latest/user_guide/initialize.html)  show this:

```
<?php
// features/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php

use Behat\Behat\Context\SnippetAcceptingContext;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\PyStringNode;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\TableNode;

class FeatureContext implements SnippetAcceptingContext
{
    /**
     * Initializes context.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it's because I don't a behat.yml file or it's other problem.

And it give me all the time this error:

```
  `FeatureContext` context class not found and can not be used.
```

Thanks

Oskar

Comment: You need to add your contexts in the behat.yml file.

Comment: can you share, where is your `.feature` and `FeatureContext.php` file present.